# comando para interfaz para cambiar ip en linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, ip, networking

Hola muy buenas tardes a todos quiero aclarar que no es que no sepa como cambiar la ip de mi linux.
a lo que me refiero es que si se que puedo hacerlo desde el comando

```
nano etc/network/interfaces
```

y se que tambien puedo hacerlo desde el comando

```
ifconfig  eth0 192.168.1.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

más bien me gustaria que alguien me recordara cual es el comando que abre una pequeña interfaz gráfica desde la misma consola linux, para una mayor referencia recuerdo que la interfaz es de color azul y puedes navegar en ella con las teclas de dirección de tu teclado. espero que alguien me ayude a recordar el comando.
muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal vez te refieres a nmtui.

Es una interfaz gráfica de consola para NetworkManager.

Comment: Si, de hecho si me refería precisamente a este comando. muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para configurar IP estática en Linux por defecto debemos modificar el fichero ubicado en **/etc/network/interfaces**, pero primero te recomiendo escanear tus interfaces de red con el comando:

```
ifconfig
```

Con este comando obtendrás la interfaz que esas usando para internet como por ejemplo **eth0** y poder modificarla. Luego puedes ir a editar el archivo **/etc/network/interfaces** con el siguiente comando:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

o si lo quiero editar gráficamente (por ejemplo con gedit):

```
gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

Para el interfaz elegida (en este caso eth0) utilizo esta configuración:

```
allow-hotplug eth0

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.100
gateway 192.168.1.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

En **address** coloca la IP que quieras configurar estáticamente y en gateway la de tu router, generalmente **192.168.1.1**. Esto depende del router y podemos revisarlo con ifconfig.

Luego reinicias el servicio:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Y listo!.

Espero que sea lo que andas buscando.

Answer (score -1):

ingresa el comando yast y te va desplegar una interfaz, adicional ejecuta el comando "service network restart" cuentame como te va espero te funcione
Saludos

Comment: Te invito a que leas: [answer] y [No tengo reputación para dejar un comentario, pero quiero decir algo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3765/107347)